# How to Change Run Time Database Name in Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
USE [AlphaGlobal]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TrInsertLocalUser]
   ON  [dbo].[Users]
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
  insert into AlphaLocal12.dbo.Users (PkUserId,Name,Address)
                                     values(
                                       (Select inserted.PkUserId from inserted),
                                       (Select inserted.Name from inserted),
                                       (Select inserted.Address from inserted),
                                       (Select inserted.ZIPCode from inserted)
                                     )

END
```

Hear I want to change runtime insert query database name like (`AlphaLocal13`, `AlphaLocal14`).

So how  to change DB name ?

Comment: Please Clearly Mention Its MYSQL or SQLSERVER?? and Remove Other Tags

Comment: It's a bad idea to have a trigger accessing anything outside of its own database - databases are the unit of recovery and availability in SQL and suddenly you're tying two databases together such that the original transaction cannot succeed if a second database is (temporarily) unavailable. Also, `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows, so your subqueries in the `INSERT` are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible approch:

```
USE [AlphaGlobal]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TrInsertLocalUser]
   ON  [dbo].[Users]
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
  DECLARE @YourDBNAME varchar(30)
  SET @YourDBNAME = 'MYDBNAME'
  SET @sqlCommand = 'insert into '+ @YourDBNAME+ '.dbo.Users (PkUserId,Name,Address)
                                       values(
                                         (Select inserted.PkUserId from inserted),
                                         (Select inserted.Name from inserted),
                                         (Select inserted.Address from inserted),
                                         (Select inserted.ZIPCode from inserted))';
  EXEC (@sqlCommand)
END
```

@yourDBNAME should be changed accordingly in your program.

Comment: I don't believe that `inserted` and `deleted` are accessible in nested scopes (e.g. the `EXEC`) - they're not available to stored procedures called from triggers, I'd expect a similar issue here.